# error in a web service use SSH devlopped with JAVA Axis

Tags: java, web-services, ssh, axis, noclassdeffounderror

i try to make a web service in JAVA (axis) which connect to a server in SSH
so i used a api called : ganymed, and it worked fine in java

but when i try to have the WSDL file whith AXis, i have an stange error "Exception - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : ch/ethz/ssh2/StreamGobbler"

### here is my file java :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;

public class ganymed
{
    public static string ssh()
    {       String res="";
        String hostname = "10.0.0.20";
        String username = "students";
        String password = "xxxx";
    try
    {
        /* Create a connection instance */

        Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);

        /* Now connect */

        conn.connect();

        /* Authenticate.
         * If you get an IOException saying something like
         * "Authentication method password not supported by the server at this stage."
         * then please check the FAQ.
         */

        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

        if (isAuthenticated == false)
            throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

        /* Create a session */

        Session sess = conn.openSession();

        sess.execCommand("uname -a && date && uptime && who");

        System.out.println("Here is some information about the remote host:");

        /* 
         * This basic example does not handle stderr, which is sometimes dangerous
         * (please read the FAQ).
         */

        InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

        while (true)
        {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            res +=line;

        }

        /* Show exit status, if available (otherwise "null") */

        System.out.println("ExitCode: " + sess.getExitStatus());

        /* Close this session */

        sess.close();

        /* Close the connection */

        conn.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(2);
    }
     return res;
         }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Obvious reason of NoClassDefFoundError is that a particular class is not available in classpath, so you need to add the jar containing `ch/ethz/ssh2/StreamGobbler` class into classpath or you need to check why it’s not available in classpath if you are expecting it to be.

Have a look at this link: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: when i try the java code alone, it work ! and when i try a basic java code "import ch.ethz.ssh2.*" in Axis, it work ! so i don't think that the probleme is in the classpath

Comment: What do you mean by saying: "java code alone"? You should clearly explain your question because I can not understand it.

Comment: I HAVE ADDED these
export CLASSPATH
export CLASSPATH=$classpath:/path/to/ganymed-ssh2-build2010.jar
and I have same pb

Comment: java alone mean that i compile and run the code java without using AXIS

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the problem, too. Finally, I copy ganymed-ssh2-263-SNAPSHOT.jar to /usr/share/tomcat6/webapp/myapp/WEB-INF/lib and fix the problem.
I guess the jar file should be integrated into myapp.war.

Comment: I use ant to build my webapp. Thus, I add the following lines into the build.xml to copy xxxxx-ssh.jar into the lib folder of my app.
      <copy todir="${build.dir}/dist/axis2/WEB-INF/lib" flatten="true">
         <fileset dir="${ssh.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
      </copy>